# SearchBar on navbar and display results in listview across the application

Tags: appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I have a use case as i need to add the searchbar in the navbar header (RightNavButton).
Searching the text should display the results in the listview in the page.

While searching existing view should be hidden and results should be shown, onCancel of SearchBar should hide the search results and show the original view.

This functionality should be across the application.
Currently i am adding the search result listview in each page and making show/hide by adding the SearchText method.

Is there any way to add/remove the search result view dynamically in each page?